# How do I say "for the present"?

Tags: translation, phrases

I need to translate "fight for the present" for a personal poem and I would like to divide it into two rows: "fight" and "for the present". Is it possible?

I'm pretty sure that something like this "現在 (to head) のために戦う" doesn't make much sense. How can I correctly do this?

Comment: When I read "fight for the present" I assumed you meant fight now and continue fighting for a while. But when I saw that you used ために I wondered if you meant that you are fighting to keep things the way they are now. It would help if you could clarify your intent.

Comment: I mean something like "fight to reach / stay in the present" as in "fight for the glory"

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @istrasci Are you asking me? I'm not saying it doesn't make sense. I'm saying the meaning is ambiguous. "do something for the present" normally means "do something now and keep doing it until some time in the future". This 'for' marks a duration, but the OP seems to be using it to mark a purpose, as in I like the present and I'm going to fight for the purpose of keeping it that way. This 'for' marks a purpose. The latter is a legitimate interpretation of the phrase but I don't think it is the one most people would understand it to be without further context.

Comment: @user3856370:  No, that was for OP.  They said, `I'm pretty sure that something like this "現在 (to head) のために戦う" doesn't make much sense`.